# eclipse не правильно выделяет пробелы при двойном клике

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse IDE 2021-09. До недавнего времени все было хорошо. При копирование кода со стороннего ресурса, бывает, что копируется пробелы. В таком случае, обычно двойным щелчком мышки по множеству пробелов выделяю весь диапазон пробелов, и заменяю на табуляции. Но в последнее время что-то случилось, выделяется с места щелчка до конца первого "слово".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жутко не приятно. Поискал в настройках поведение выделения, так и не нашел.

Comment: может оно просто обновилось? я кратко посмотрел на описание новых фич - они похоже даже ctrl_V сломали - оно теперь делает "умную вставку".

Comment: ну да, после обновления эклипса, такая хрен.

Comment: откатывайте назад. И напишите им багрепорт. Хотя...